# Creating curves that satisfy $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$

Tags: graphics

All, I haven't experienced this task in Mathematica yet, maybe using Bezier curves, Interpolation, or some such thing to create the following image.

[image]

Can someone give me an introduction to accomplishing this? The three functions have to satisfy $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ near $x=a$ and I want them all to have the same value at $x=a$. This is an image I intend to use when explaining the Squeeze Theorem to students.

Thanks.

**Update:** All, here is as close as I've gotten thus far.

```
Graphics[{
  {Black, Dashed, Thick, Line[{{0, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 0}}]},
  Orange, Thick,
  BezierCurve[{{-1, 7}, {0, 13}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}}],
  BezierCurve[{{5, 5}, {6, 5}, {8, 10}, {10, 7}}],
  Red,
  BezierCurve[{{-1, 10}, {0, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}}],
  BezierCurve[{{5, 5}, {6, 5}, {8, 4}, {10, 6}}],
  Blue,
  BezierCurve[{{-1, 2}, {0, 5}, {2, 4}, {4, 4.6}}],
  BezierCurve[{{4, 4.6}, {4.2, 4.7}, {4.8, 5}, {5, 5}}],
  BezierCurve[{{5, 5}, {5.2, 5}, {5.4, 4.7}, {6, 4.6}}],
  BezierCurve[{{6, 4.6}, {8, 4}, {9, 5}, {10, 3}}],
  Text[Style["f", Blue, 12], {10.3, 3}],
  Text[Style["g", Red, 12], {10.3, 6}],
  Text[Style["h", Orange, 12], {10.3, 7}],
  Text[Style["a", Black, 12], {5, -0.3}],
  Text[Style["L", Black, 12], {-0.3, 5}]
  },
 Axes -> True,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {-1, 10}},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: You want code that randomly generates three functions satisfying those conditions?

Comment: you can have thousands of such solutions, you need to be more specific. `{-(x - a)^2 + b, 2 (x - a)^2 + b, 4 (x - a)^2 + b}` satisfies the condition but is that want you want?

Comment: @Algohi et al. I want to create a picture that looks exactly like the one shown in my post.

Comment: "Exactly" like it? It sure looks to me like it was drawn by hand (in an illustration program).

Comment: Hmm... $g(x)$ is not ≤ $h(x)$ somewhere past $x<0$...

Comment: @R.M. You are correct. I've edited my post. Should have said $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ near $x=a$.

Comment: @Rahul Probably true, but how close can we get?

Answer (score 12):

> I want to create a picture that looks exactly like the one shown in my post. – David

Well, here are the curves....

First, grab and crop the image:

```
i1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAifP.png"];
i2 = ImageTake[i1, {170, 400}, {160, 570}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

White out the white part:

```
i3 = ImageAdjust[ImageAdjust[i2], {0, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Find the limit point: It is at the intersection of lines 3 and 5 in the [`ImageLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageLines.html) list.  (I also thought I would rotate the image and correct the perspective, but my image-processing mojo wasn't working.)

```
lines = ImageLines[Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize@i3, 0.14]
{ptA} = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{Line /@ lines[[{3, 5}]]}]
(*
  {{{0., 42.6307}, {411., 59.8568}}, {{71.3855, 231.}, {47.1064, 0.}},
   {{0., 132.991}, {411., 150.217}}, {{0., 65.155}, {411., 230.733}},
   {{211.989, 231.}, {225.135, 0.}}}

  {{217.049, 142.088}}
*)
```

Check it out:

```
Show[
 i3,
 Graphics[{Thick, Purple, Line /@ lines[[{3, 5}]],
   PointSize[Large], Orange, Point[ptA]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now separate the graphs.  Oh, it took a little trial and error to get the right colors, which is evident in the odd numeric parameters found here and there.  I mapped the `f` line to `Red`, `g` to `Green` and `h` to `Blue`, so that [`ColorSeparate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorSeparate.html) could extract the graphs.  Everything else was mapped to `Black`.

```
nf = Nearest[{
     {1, 1, 1}, 0.8 {1, 1, 1}, 0.6 {1, 1, 1}, 0.4 {1, 1, 1}, 
     0.2 {1, 1, 1},
     0.9 {1, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.9, 0.7, 0.4},
     0.9 {1, 1, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.2}, {1, 1, 0.6},
     0.9 {0.5, 0.5, 1}, 0.6 {0.2, 0.2, 1}} ->
    {0 {1, 1, 1}, 0 {1, 1, 1}, 0 {1, 1, 1}, 0 {1, 1, 1}, 0 {1, 1, 1},
     {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1},
     {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}];
rgb0 = ColorSeparate[ImageApply[First@*nf, i3]];
rgb3 = (Binarize[#, 0.05] &) /@
  MapAt[DeleteSmallComponents[#, Method -> "Mean"] &, rgb0, 3]
```

Now fit an interpolating function to each graph.  I added the limit point, specifying the derivatives at the point, in the hopes that the interpolating functions would stay in the right order near the point.  Well, after more fiddling, it helps to push $A$ over a little

```
ptA = ptA + {6, 1};

Clear[if];
if[pts_] /; VectorQ[Flatten[pts], NumericQ] := Interpolation[pts];

xrange = Range[0, 400, 40];

fgh = Table[Module[{data, datanf, sol},
    data = PixelValuePositions[img, 1];
    With[{d = DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@data}, 
     datanf = Nearest[d[[All, 1]] -> d[[All, 2]]]];

    sol = 
     FindFit[data, 
      if[SortBy[First]@
         Append[Table[{{x1}, y[x1]}, {x1, xrange}], {{ptA[[1]]}, ptA[[2]], 0.07}]][x], 
      Table[{y[x1], First@datanf[x1]}, {x1, xrange}], x];
    if[Sort@Append[Table[{x1, y[x1]}, {x1, xrange}], ptA] /. sol]
    ],
   {img, rgb3}];
```

Check out the results:

```
Show[
 ImageAdd @@ rgb3 // ImageAdjust,
 Plot[Through[fgh[x]] // Evaluate, {x, 35, 365}],
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Wow, pretty good.

The beginnings of the figure:

```
axO = {55, 75};
Plot[Through[fgh[x]] // Evaluate, {x, 35, 365},
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Ticks -> {{{ptA[[1]], HoldForm@A}}, {{ptA[[2]], HoldForm@L}}},
 AxesOrigin -> axO, AxesStyle -> Black,
 Prolog -> {Dashed, 
   Line[{{ptA[[1]], axO[[2]]}, ptA, {axO[[1]], ptA[[2]]}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @MichealE2 You are having so much fun with this question. This is really something I have to figure out. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 8):

Given the use case, I don't think it is worth the time to reproduce this "exactly" by inferring the underlying equations or doing some image processing and fitting a curve, etc. You can reproduce this image to a reasonable accuracy by eyeballing some numbers, while staying true to the spirit of the image.

This took me less than 5 minutes:

```
f = {{-1, 1}, {0, 1.5}, {1, 1.25}, {2, 1.75}, {2.5, 1.85}, {3, 2}, {4,1.75}, {5, 1}, {6, 0.5}};
g = {{-1, 4}, {0, 2.5}, {1, 2}, {2, 1.85}, {2.5, 1.95}, {3, 2}, {4, 1.85}, {5, 2.2}, {6, 2.25}};
h = {{-1, 2.5}, {0, 3}, {1, 3.25}, {2, 2.5}, {2.5, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2.75}, {6, 2.85}};

With[{
  func = BSplineCurve[#,
     SplineKnots -> "Unclamped",
     SplineDegree -> 2,
     SplineWeights -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1}
     ] &,
  colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"]
  },
 Graphics[{
   {colors[[1]], func[f]},
   {colors[[4]], func[g]},
   {colors[[2]], func[h]},
   Text[#, Symbol[#][[-1]]] & /@ {"f", "g", "h"},
   {Dashed, Line[{{0, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 0}}]}
   },
  Axes -> True,
  Ticks -> {{{0, 0}, {3, "a"}}, {{0, 0}, {2, "L"}}},
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 4}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. This will be an excellent introduction for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like a little thought about the underlying calculus helps construct likely candidates.  The rest is just work.  Interpolations galore!

```
Clear[drunkenwalk];
sigmoid = Exp[#]/(1 + Exp[#]) &;
rescale[s_] := 1/2 + s (# - 1/2) &;
witch = #^2/(1 + #^2) &;
drunkenwalk[x_, f1_, f2_, wobble_, scale_: 1] :=
 (1 - rescale[scale]@sigmoid[wobble[x]]) f1[x] + 
  rescale[scale]@sigmoid[wobble[x]] f2[x]

Block[{
  f1 = -witch[#] &, f2 = -2 witch[#] &,
  h1 = witch[#] &, h2 = 2 witch[#] &,
  wf, wg, wh, f, g, h},
 wf = Interpolation[Table[{x, RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, {x, -2, 2}], 
   Method -> "Spline"];
 wh = Interpolation[Table[{x, RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, {x, -2, 2}], 
   Method -> "Spline"];
 f = Evaluate@drunkenwalk[#, f1, f2, wf] &;
 h = Evaluate@drunkenwalk[#, h1, h2, wh] &;
 wg = Interpolation[
   ReplacePart[Table[{x, RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, {x, -2, 2, 4/5}], 1 -> {-2, 3}],
     Method -> "Spline"];
 g = Evaluate@drunkenwalk[#, f, h, wg, 1/2 + #^2] &;
 Plot[3 + {f[x - 1.5], h[x - 1.5], g[x - 1.5]}, {x, -0.5, 3.5}, 
  Evaluated -> True]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow. I'll definitely be studying your technique. Thanks so much.

Comment: @David Thanks & you're welcome.  As a pedagogical aside, I think I'd rather draw $f$ and $h$ on a chalkboard and ask the students to help me try to draw a function $g$ that stays between $f$ and $h$ but does **not** have the limit $L$ at $a$.